# How to output <ul> and <li> elements from XML to XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several unordered lists in an XML file that I need to convert to HTML with an XSL file. These lists inside my XML look like:

```
<Food>
   <FoodItem ID="1">
      <Content><![CDATA[<ul><li>Apples</li><li>Pears</li><li>Oranges</li><ul>]]></Content>
   </FoodItem>
</Food>
```

I would like to grab the unordered lists from the XML file and output them in my XSL file like so that I can stlye them with CSS. The result should be like this:

```
<div class="food">
    <ul class="fooditems">
        <li class="fooditem">Apples</li>
        <li class="fooditem">Pears</li>
        <li class="fooditem">Oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, `<xsl:value-of select="key('fooditem', 1)/Content` only gave me a string of `<ul><li>Apples</li><li>Pears</li><li>Oranges</li></ul>`.

The key is defined as `<xsl:key name="fooditem" match="FoodItem" use="@ID" />`.

How can I get the individual list tags including their content out of the `<![CDATA[]]>` tag?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the individual list tags including their content out of the  tag?

For an XSLT-1.0 solution, you have to use a two step approach:

1. Get the items out of the CDATA section.
2. Apply the templates you want to apply.

One problem is that the CDATA sample is not *well-formed* XML. So you have to change your input XML (changing the last `<ul>` to `</ul>`) to the following:

```
<Food>
   <FoodItem ID="1">
      <Content><![CDATA[<ul><li>Apples</li><li>Pears</li><li>Oranges</li></ul>]]></Content>
   </FoodItem>
</Food>
```

For the first step you can use this (assuming that your XSLT processor does support the [disable-output-escaping](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#disable-output-escaping) attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::text())]|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="text()">            
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you can apply your XSLT template to the output of the above stylesheet.

The result of this transformation should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Food>
    <FoodItem ID="1">
        <Content>
            <ul>
                <li>Apples</li>
                <li>Pears</li>
                <li>Oranges</li>
            <ul>
        </Content>
    </FoodItem>
</Food>
```

Now, the second step is applying a different XSLT-1.0 stylesheet to this output.
So apply this second XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Food/FoodItem/Content/ul">    
        <div class="food">
            <ul class="fooditems">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li"> 
        <li class="fooditem"><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
    </xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of this second step is:

```
<div class="food">
    <ul class="fooditems">
        <li class="fooditem">Apples</li>
        <li class="fooditem">Pears</li>
        <li class="fooditem">Oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which is as desired.

## SOLVED!

---

With newer versions of XSLT processors (3.0 and above) you can (possibly) do both steps in one stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you, this works so far. But I cannot figure out what its meant by "Now you can apply your XSLT template to the output of the above stylesheet." Could you help me with this as well?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `ul`/`li` elements are not as nodes in your input XML but rather as escaped markup in a CDATA section. So you would need to parse that markup before being able to transform nodes. With XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 and later or AltovaXML 2017 and later) you can use the `parse-xml` or `parse-xml-fragment` XPath 3 function to parse a string with an XML document or an XML fragment into nodes.

However, at least in your question's sample, the escaped markup is not well-formed XML as it doesn't have a properly closed `ul` element, it is `<ul><li>Apples</li><li>Pears</li><li>Oranges</li><ul>` where it should be `<ul><li>Apples</li><li>Pears</li><li>Oranges</li></ul>` to be parseable as XML.

So depending on the real sample, if that is well-formed, you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="FoodItem">
      <div class="food">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(Content)/node()" mode="food"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode name="food" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="ul" mode="food">
      <ul class="fooditems">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="li" mode="food">
      <li class="fooditem">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

as shown in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZH/1 and get your wanted output

```
   <div class="food">
      <ul class="fooditems">
         <li class="fooditem">Apples</li>
         <li class="fooditem">Pears</li>
         <li class="fooditem">Oranges</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help!