# How to get substring with paragraph tags but ignore substring not containing text?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently fetching first paragraph of an article but some of them contain just an image.

How to get first paragraph that does not contain image and contains text?

This is my code:

```
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring-before(substring-after(copy, '&lt;p&gt;'), '&lt;/p&gt;') " />
        <a href="{$currentPage/url}" title="{$currentPage/title}: {@nodeName}">
          Continue reading...
        </a>
```

The result may be:

```
<p>some text...</p>
```

but the result maybe also:

```
<p><img /></p>
```

I want to filter off the second case. Or more specifically speaking - I want to filter off any `<p>` that do not contain any text.

How to do it?

Comment: It appears you are trying to parse escaped XML as text. It might be much easier to convert it to XML first, then use XPath to parse it.

Comment: @michael how to do it in xslt?

Comment: Depends on your version. See this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510413/how-to-output-ul-and-li-elements-from-xml-to-xsl

Comment: I'm using version 1.0 and the v1 example from the above url is of no use to me, it just does display html from within `cdata` @michael and I want to filter html to display.

Comment: If you're using XSLT 1.0, then your best option IMHO is to de-escape the XML as shown in the example I pointed to, save the result to a file, and process the interim file with a separate stylesheet.